# Execute JPA/JPQL with CASE WHEN statement with numbers and strings

Tags: sql, oracle, jpa, eclipselink, jpql

I have this sql:

```
SELECT 
    PERSONAL.NUMERO_DCTO, 
    PERSONAL.ID_DE_EMPLEADO,  
    (PERSONAL.APELLIDO1 || ' ' || PERSONAL.APELLIDO2 || ' ' || PERSONAL.NOMBRES) AS NOMBRE_COMP, 
    CASE ESTADO_ACTUAL 
        WHEN 1 THEN 'ACTIVO' 
        WHEN 2 THEN 'PENSIONADO' 
        WHEN 3 THEN 'RETIRADO'
        .... 
        ELSE 'OTRO' 
    END AS ESTADO_ACTUAL 
FROM PERSONAL
```

note: .... means more conditions
It is a simple sql statement, and the field estado_actual is a number field in oracle. The resulting of mapping is a class named personal with a field called "private Integer estadoActual"

And i NEED it to run in jpa context (Keeping database independent)

So, i have converted to this jpql format query:

```
SELECT 
    personalm.numeroDcto, 
    personalm.idDeEmpleado, 
    ( CONCAT( CONCAT( CONCAT( CONCAT(personalm.apellido1,' ') ,personalm.apellido2) ,' ') ,personalm.nombres) ) AS NOMBRE_COMP, 
    CASE personalm.estadoActual 
        WHEN 1 THEN 'ACTIVO' 
        WHEN... 
    END AS ESTADO_ACTUAL 
FROM Personal personalm
```

Problem comes when i want to execute the last one, as it tries to convert the 'activo' label to Integer, and gives me this error:

> Exception Description: The object [ACTIVO], of class [class java.lang.String], from mapping [org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.DirectToFieldMapping[estadoActual-->PERSONAL.ESTADO_ACTUAL]] with descriptor [RelationalDescriptor(nomina2019.Personal --> [DatabaseTable(PERSONAL)])], could not be converted to [class java.lang.Integer].\nInternal Exception: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: \"ACTIVO\"

I have tried with no luck converting the estadoActual field to char and some other workarounds (in the jpql query).

How i should modify the jpql query in order to execute it in jpql context?
I'm using eclipselink 2.7.4 and eql(jpql with eclipselink extensions) as the  jpa provider.

Please keep in mind that changing the field from Integer to String or something like that as i need the Personal Database and Personal Entity as it is know.

Comment: I don't know a lot about jpa, but if `PERSONAL.ESTADO_ACTUAL` is as a string, then you might need to compare it as a string in the `CASE` statement : I mean change `CASE personalm.estadoActual WHEN 1 THEN 'ACTIVO' ` to `CASE personalm.estadoActual WHEN '1' THEN 'ACTIVO' `

Comment: ..or you have to convert estadoActual to  String or you have to select a number! (but the query might have more issues `AS`)

Comment: @GMB i have tried that but then oracle throws and exception called: ORA-00932, as it waits for a number and got a char (PERSONAL.ESTADO_ACTUAL) is a number

Comment: First, why? If you have a Personalm class that maps 1:1 the fields in PERSONAL as you seem, why not just take the ESTADO_ACTUAL as an integer and convert it to string in code? This doesn't seem like something you need built into the Database query.  Same with the concatenation logic, create a java getNombreComp method to display this concatenated string.  Return the java object representing your data and let your application logic decide what is displayed from it.  Otherwise, how are you pulling and displaying this raw data anyway?

Comment: @Chris i'm not the master or mainteiner of the logic behind the scenes, the reason is that the actual sql query is a part of a complete module that i'm migrating from pl/sql to java due to platform changes. (The actual module cannot be changed as it is and will continue served in production) In this order, i need all the sql queries to work with jpa/jpql, to work with a new module that depends someway of the other. The Personal entity was already mapped for that previous module.

Comment: I have yet to see a project using SQL and getting raw data that couldn't be changed to using java objects wrapping those results when making other changes to use JPA, but yours might the first. Functionality doesn't need to change, as methods executing the query can abstract out the model and query used underneath and return the data in what ever form the callers need. Otherwise - what is the point -you can just use the SQL as a native query since the callers have been dependent on the database specific operations anyway.

Comment: Otherwise - what is the mapping used for the personalm.estadoActual field? And how are you returning these results?  The query is expecting an integer but getting a string, so you have a problem in the results you are building due to your case statement converting the int values to strings.